# запись в файл в формате JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

Мне  нужно  записать в jsonObject вопросы и ответы
Я  делаю  так:

```
 const Task* task = dynamic_cast<const Task*>(component);
  if (task != nullptr)
  {
      std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject;
      jsonObject["classType"] = ClassType::TASK;
      jsonObject["question"] = task->question();
      jsonObject["answer"] = task->answer();
      jsonObject["numPoints"] = task->numPoints();

      return jsonObject;
  }
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
1)  error: C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand 
operand of type 'std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' (or 
there is no acceptable conversion)
with
[
  _Ty=QJsonObject
]
```

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan выдает ошибку:  illegal index, indirection not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы обернули json , объект в unique_ptr, тел, что бы использовать оператор [ ] необходимо достать объект, используете *.

Подводя итог, полное решение, обсуждаемое в комментариях:

```
#include <QJsonObject>

std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> obj = std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>(new QJsonObject);
(*jsonObject)["classType"] = static_cast<int>(ClassType::TASK);
(*jsonObject)["question"] = task->question();
(*jsonObject)["answer"] = task->answer();
(*jsonObject)["numPoints"] = int(task->numPoints());
```

Необходимо подключить правильный заголовочный файл, перед использованием указателя, инициализировать его. Использовать оператор * для получения объекта и применения к нему оператора **[ ]**, и привести все типы к целым числам, и строкам.

Comment: @R.Mazgudov не совсем понял как указатель использовать. Напишите пример

Comment: (*jsonObject)["classType"]

Comment: Кроме того у вас ошибка, вы не создали объект, и память для него не выделели. Надо сделать std::unique_ptr<...> = std::make_unique();

Comment: @R.Masgutov std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject= std::make_unique<QJsonObject>(5); так норм?

Comment: если так напишу: (*jsonObject)["classType"] = ClassType::TASK; ошибка -  error: C2676: binary '[': 'QJsonObject' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: Надо привести ваш тип ClassType к целому числу, static_cast<int>(ClassType::TASK), вероятно, оператор = не может привести к целому числу

Comment: та нет. оно к  этому тоже ошибку выдает туже  (*jsonObject)["question"] = task->question();
        (*jsonObject)["answer"] = task->answer();
        (*jsonObject)["numPoints"] = task->numPoints();

Comment: А если убрать 5 из конструктора? Т.е. просто make_unique<QJsonObject>();

Comment: убрал. ошибка осталась

Comment: А если сделать jsonObject.get()["question"]? Нет компьютера с qt под рукой.

Comment: выдает ошибку: illegal index, indirection not allowed

Comment: Вернёмся к предыдущей версии, что возвращают ваши методы? Я использовал вот такуюже конструкцию но передал строковые литералы, и у меня все работает

Comment: @R.Marzgudov QString/ Скиньте свое. может я  не так  делаю ,  так  будет проще

Comment: std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> obj = std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject>(new QJsonObject);
    (*obj)["key"] = "value";

Comment: у меня и  на ваш код ошибку выдает

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос версию qt, и все заголовочные файлы которые вы используете

Comment: решилась проблема, я в инклуде  не правильно написал QJsonObject.  Теперь только тут кричит:  (*jsonObject)["numPoints"] = task->numPoints();

Comment: unsigned numPoints() const; моя функция

Comment: Простое решение привести значение в знаковое целое, т.е. в просто int. И судя по всему так и нужно сделать, это можно сделать обернув вызов метода в int(...)